# How do I print the actions done by previous functions using for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

As an assignment I am making a simple interface in python which can show a balance, add to that balance, take out money from that balance, check the interest rate and then lastly check the three previous actions done. This will be choice == 5. So what do I write in the bottom def in order to do so?

```
usd = 500

def main():
    print("""
    1. Balance
    2. Add
    3. Retrieve
    4. Interest
    5. Last Changes
    """)

    choice = int(input("Choose: "))

    if choice == 1:
        global usd
        balance()
    elif choice == 2:
        add()
    elif choice == 3:
        retrieve()
    elif choice == 4:
        interest()
    elif choice == 5:
        changes()

def balance():
    global usd
    print("Balance: ", round((usd),2))
    main()

def add():
    global usd
    amount = int(input("How much do you want to add? "))
    usd = amount + usd
    print("New balance = ", round((usd),2))
    main()

def retrieve():
    global usd
    amount = int(input("How much do you want to retrieve: "))
    usd = usd - amount
    print("New balance = ", round((usd),2))  
    main()

def interest():
    global usd
    if usd<=1000000:
        usd = ((usd/100)*101)
        print("New balance: ", round(((usd/100)*101), 2))
    elif usd>=1000000:
        usd = ((usd/100)*102)
        print("New balance: ", round(((usd/100)*102), 2))
    main()

def changes(): 
    
    main()

main()
```

The desired output will look a little like this;

```
Choose: 5
+6105
-500000
+1110000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback).

Comment: Has your class taught you about classes/objects yet?  FWIW if they're teaching you to do everything with global state they're teaching you bad habits that you'll need to spend time unlearning later.  :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep a log of the previous actions. You could do this by creating a list and appending a new entry each time an action is done. Then your changes function could print out the last 3 items in the list.

You could make the list global and access it in the same way you access `usd`.

You could also make the list in main and pass it to changes as an argument. If you decide to do it this way, you could make each function return their log so that you can append it to the list in main.

For example (using only the add function illustrate)

Using a global variable (this is bad practice, but is shorter):

```
usd = 500
log = []

def add():
    global usd
    amount = int(input("How much do you want to add? "))
    usd = amount + usd
    print("New balance = ", round((usd),2))
    log.append(f"+{amount}")    # add change to log
    main()

def changes(): 
    # print last 3 items in log
    for change in log[-3:]:
        print(change)
    main()
```

Or the more typical way, using a loop (without a global variable)

```
usd = 500

def main():
    log = []
    choice = 0
    while choice != 6:

        print("""
        1. Balance
        2. Add
        3. Retrieve
        4. Interest
        5. Last Changes
        6. Quit
        """)

        choice = int(input("Choose: "))

        if choice == 1:
            balance()
        elif choice == 2:
            log.append(add())      # add change to log
        elif choice == 3:
            log.append(retrieve()) # add change to log
        elif choice == 4:
            interest()
       elif choice == 5:
            changes(log)


def add():
    global usd
    amount = int(input("How much do you want to add? "))
    usd = amount + usd
    print("New balance = ", round((usd),2))
    return f"+{amount}"


def changes(log): 
    # print last 3 items in log
    for change in log[-3:]:
        print(change)

main()
```

A potential problem with this approach is because you are adding items to the log list indefinitely, theoretically you may eventually run out of memory on your computer. To remedy, you can remove extra logs from the list whenever the length of the list is greater than 3.

Documentation for lists: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Global variables are bad practice in general, so it would be preferable to avoid making usd a global variable, but I'll leave that up to you

Comment: Would you mind providing an example for this? Cant figure out how you add a new entry each time an action is done nor make the function return its log. Thanks

Comment: @eirvav I added an example